# Fast way to compute Fréchet/Gateaux Derivatives

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, frechet-derivative, variational-analysis, gateaux-derivative

I was wondering if there is any fast way to compute Fréchet/Gateaux Derivatives, or at least a reasonable guess in most cases, say from the usual derivatives table.

The Fréchet derivatives $\dfrac{\delta F}{\delta x}$of a functional $F: (X,||\cdot||)\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is defined, if exists, as the functional $\dfrac{\delta F}{\delta x}: (X,||\cdot||)\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\lim_{||h||\to 0}\dfrac{|F(x+h)-F(x)-\frac{\delta F}{\delta x}(h)|}{||h||}=0.$$

The Gateaux derivatives $\mathrm{d}F(x;h)$ of a functional $F: (X,||\cdot||)\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ in the direction $h\in X$ is defined, if exists,
$$dF(x;h) = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \dfrac{F(x+\varepsilon h)-F(x)}{\varepsilon}.$$

Comment: This question is way too broad. Do you have specific examples of functionals in mind?

Comment: We should have this $\frac{\delta F}{\delta x}(x)$. And as @daw said i found it very brand to.

Comment: There is if the functionals you have are integral functionals with elementary functions under the integral. That's what the [classical calculus of variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations#Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) is about. But speaking generally, why would there be any relation between some abstract functionals and the usual table of derivatives for elementary functions?

Comment: @Conifold for example, the functional $\mathcal{V}: \mu \mapsto \int V\mathrm{d}\mu$ has the first variation as $\dfrac{\delta \mathcal{V}}{\delta \mu}=V$ in the sense of $\dfrac{\delta \mathcal{V}}{\delta \mu}(\nu)= \langle V,\nu\rangle$, provided with a suitable space for $\mu$ to live in. This reminders taking a derivative of a linear function. For the functional $\mathcal{W}:\mu \mapsto \int W(x,y)\mathrm{d}\mu(x)\mathrm{d}\mu(y)$ has a Frechet derivative, which looks like a product rule in the usual derivatives, but I cannot convince myself.

Comment: @daw I replied to Conifold with two known examples, while I am interested into some functional defined in a form of "sup/inf", and look for the relationship between its Frechet/Gateaux derivatives with the usual derivative, so that to compute Frechet/Gateaux derivatives in a formal but correct way.

Comment: I am guessing $\mu$ is a measure? The more usual setting is to deal with densities $d\mu=f(x)dx$, and what you wrote are integrals linear and quadratic in densities, so of course it is directly related to elementary derivatives. More generally, $\int L(x,y; f(x),f(y);f'(x),f'(y))\,dxdy$ and the like, where $L$ is some elementary function in $f$ and $f'$, are handled by the calculus of variations. But $\sup/\inf$ functionals are not of this sort.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to quickly calculate Gateaux derivatives. It can also be used to calculate Frechet derivatives, if you are sure that a functional is Frechet differentiable, because in this case the Gateaux derivative also exists and coincides with the Frechet derivative.

Note that
$$F(f+th): \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},\ \text{fixed}\ f\in X,\ h\ \text{admissible}, t\in\mathbb{R}$$
$$\frac{dF(f+th)}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{F(f+th)-F(f)}{t}=dF(f;h)$$
Example: take the functional
$$\int_0^1||f'(x)||^2dx,\ \text{restrict to}\ f(0)=a,\ f(1)=b$$
This is a convex functional over a convex set. For differentiable $h(x)\ \text{s.t.}\ h(0)=0,h(1)=0$:
$$F(f+th)=\int_0^1||f'(x)+th'(x)||^2dx=\int_0^1||f'(x)||^2+2tf'(x)\cdot h'(x)+t^2||h'(x)||^2dx$$
$$dF(f;h)=\frac{dF(f+th)}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}=\int_0^12f'(x)\cdot h'(x)dx=\int_0^12f''(x)h(x)dx$$
Note that $dF(f;h)=0$ when $f$ is the straight line from $a$ to $b$, this is the minimum of the functional.